# Customizing the error messages for the standard validators

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a simple form:

```
  val addForm = Form(
    tuple("email" -> email, "password" -> nonEmptyText)
      verifying("Invalid email or password", result => User.authenticate(result._1, result._2).isRight)
  )
```

The general error message above is ok. But how do I customize the specific error messages for the email and password. For now in case of empty password I've got this kind of error:

```
password error.required
```

How do I customize this error message?

**UPDATE**:
Even this doesn't work because the validation message is still the same as it was:

```
val addForm = Form(
        tuple("email" -> email, "password" -> nonEmptyTextWithMessage("My message"))
          verifying("Invalid email or password", result => User.authenticate(result._1, result._2).isRight)
      )


def nonEmptyTextWithMessage(errorMessage: String): Mapping[String] = nonEmptyText.verifying(errorMessage, { _ => true })
```

Comment: Have you tried using the conf/messages file and it does not suit you? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaI18N

Answer (score 1):

The `nonEmptyText` constraint defaults to using `error.required` as message key. You could change that in your `conf/messages` file, but I suppose this is not what you want.

If you want to re-use a pre-defined `Constraint` (note that `nonEmptyText` is not a `Constraint` but a `Mapping`), you could do the following:

```
val addForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email" -> email,
    "password" -> text.verifying(Constraints.nonEmpty.copy(name = Some("My message"))())
   ).verifying("Invalid email or password", result => User.authenticate(result._1, result._2).isRight)
)
```

It does not look very nice, but I'm not aware of any helper function that would achieve the same.

Comment: I'd like not use this `password => password != null && password.trim.nonEmpty` because it duplicates nonEmptyText constraint. How can I do the same using nonEmptyText?

Answer (score 1):

My colleague suggest, If you are using scala template, you could customize error message as follows

just add

```
'_error ->addForm("password").error.map(_.withMessage("Please provide password"))
```

like

```
 @helper.inputPassword(addForm("password"), 'class->"col-md-12", '_label ->"Password",'style->"margin-bottom:20px", '_showConstraints->false, 'placeholder->"Enter Password", '_error ->addForm("password").error.map(_.withMessage("Please provide password")))
```